# Change url of storage image on submit infirebase with angular / angularfire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire, firebase-storage

I've finally manage to have my upload to storage functionality working perfectly into my firebase storage running with Angular and Angularfire. I'm starting to develop with Angular.

for that I'm using that form:

```
<form ng-submit="uploadFile(file)">
<input type="file" accept="txt" file-model="file" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
```

and that js:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$firebaseStorage',function($scope,     $firebaseStorage) {

// Create a Firebase Storage reference
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var filesRef = storageRef.child('files');

$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
console.log("Let's upload a file!");
console.log($scope.file);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name).put(file);
storageRef.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        }, function() {
            //handle error
        }, function() {
       //url of storage file 
            var downloadURL = storageRef .snapshot.downloadURL;
     console.log(downloadURL);

        });
    };

 }]);
```

I've added

```
console.log(downloadURL);
```

in my DownloadUrl Var, and I can see the url of the fie being upload display fine in the console.

However, i'd like the url to be updated in the database as well.

EXample:

I add below my form an input where an storage file path is being dispaly from the database ( it works fine):

```
<form ng-submit="uploadFile(file)">
<input type="file" accept="txt" file-model="file" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
<input ng-model="group.imageDetails" ng-change="groups.$save(group)" />
```

this is being fetch from that:

```
    app.controller("VideosCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
  var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");

 $scope.groups = $firebaseObject(ref);

  // download the data into a local object
  var syncObject = $firebaseObject(ref);
  // synchronize the object with a three-way data binding
  // click on `index.html` above to see it used in the DOM!
  syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "data");
});
```

What id like is when I submit the file to upload, to update the input below my form with the download URL of that new file just uploaded.

How can this be achieve ?

Thanks a lot for your help everyone !

--- EDIT:

OK with the code below:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$firebaseStorage',function($scope,     $firebaseStorage) {

// Create a Firebase Storage reference
var storage = firebase.storage();
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts')
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var filesRef = storageRef.child('files');

$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
console.log("Let's upload a file!");
console.log($scope.file);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name).put(file);
storageRef.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

    }, function() {
        //handle error
    }, function() {
   //url of storage file 
        var downloadURL = storageRef .snapshot.downloadURL;
       firebaseRef.update({'test':downloadURL})

 console.log(downloadURL);

    });
};

 }]);
```

it create it but in the wrong table of my database:

```
    --mydomain 
----posts 
--------POST LIST1 
------------author 
------------imageDetails ( THIS is where it should update the url) 
--------CURRENT URL ( This is wehre it is save at the moment) 
----users 
--------name 
--------email 
--------id
```

so i tried to replace

```
firebaseRef.update({'test':downloadURL})
```

by

```
firebaseRef.update().ref().child('posts').child({'test':downloadURL});
```

but no luck ...  does anybody have a solution ?

Thanks @

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope','$firebaseStorage',function($scope,     $firebaseStorage) {

// Create a Firebase Storage reference
var storage = firebase.storage();
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('posts')
var storageRef = storage.ref();
var filesRef = storageRef.child('files');

$scope.uploadFile = function(file) {
console.log("Let's upload a file!");
console.log($scope.file);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child(file.name).put(file);
storageRef.on('state_changed', function(snapshot) {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        }, function() {
            //handle error
        }, function() {
       //url of storage file 
            var downloadURL = storageRef .snapshot.downloadURL;
         // $scope.group.imageDetails = downloadURL;
          firebaseRef.update({'url':downloadURL})
     console.log(downloadURL);

        });
    };

 }]);
```

It will upload url in database **posts**

```
app.controller("VideosCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseObject) {
 var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("posts");

 ref.on('value',function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.val().url);
 $scope.groups = snapshot.val().url;
 });
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <form ng-submit="uploadFile(file)">
<input type="file" accept="txt" file-model="file" class="form-control">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload File</button>
<input ng-model="groups"/>
```